# How to test iosched 2012?

Tags: android, iosched

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

I'm fairly new to android development.
I can launch the app in the emulator, but cannot proceed further.
Its 'add account' button do nothing.

Does this app run only on device?

How do I regiter an account for this app? would any google account suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes some functionality possible only on device, but you can try also [BlueStacks App Player](http://bluestacks.com/) which has more possibilities than Android emulator.